# How to check word is exist in current directory

Tags: linux, shell

I have two files each containing:

`file.txt`

```
hello, good morning
```

`file1.txt`

```
hello, goodnight
```

`file.txt`,`file1.txt`,`app.sh` is in the same directory

So I tried to find the word "hello" but it didn't come up

```
$ sh app.sh
Hey there, what are you looking for?(file/text) text
Enter word hello
Word 'hello' does not exist
```

my output:`Word 'hello' does not exist`

my `app.sh`:

```
echo -e "Hey there, what are you looking for?(file/text) \c"
read str
if [ $str = "file" ] 
then
    echo -e  "Enter file name \c"
    read file
    if [ -f $file ]
    then 
        echo
        echo "File '$file' is exist in"
        realpath $file
        echo
        echo "Content $file":
        cat $file
    else
        echo "File '$file' is does not exist"
    fi
elif [ $str = "text" ]
then
    echo -e "Enter word \c"
    read word
    if  [ -w $word ] 
    then
        echo
        echo "word '$word' you are looking for is in the file": 
        grep -iRl "$word"
    else
        echo "Word '$word' does not exist"
    fi
else
    echo "You entered the wrong command"
fi    
}
```

I just learned shell scripting for 1 week, I don't know where it went wrong. Hope you can solve this problem

Comment: It is helpful to provide a minimal example that demonstrate the problem.  In this case either hard-code the input or tell us what you used.

Comment: @AllanWind I've tried before without using the -w syntax. so I just used the if
[ $word ] and it works, but when I search for a word that doesn't exist, the command else is not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
if  [ -w $word ]
```

-w option expects a FILE name. So if a FILE exists and the write permission is granted, then only if statement will be true. Since you don't have a file called hello, it is going to else block. For more info on if options you may look at [this](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-if-statements.php).

You can try getting results from grep and check if it is empty or not as below:

```
echo -e "Hey there, what are you looking for?(file/text) \c"
read str
if [ $str = "file" ] 
then
    echo -e  "Enter file name \c"
    read file
    if [ -f $file ]
    then 
        echo
        echo "File '$file' is exist in"
        realpath $file
        echo
        echo "Content $file":
        cat $file
    else
        echo "File '$file' is does not exist"
    fi
elif [ $str = "text" ]
then
    echo -e "Enter word \c"
    read word
    res=$(grep -iRl $word)
    # check if non-empty res
    if [ -n "$res" ]
    then
        echo "word '$word' you are looking for is in the file":
        echo "$res"
    else
        echo "Word '$word' does not exist"
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you used in the input `text` and `hello`.  The `if  [ -w $word ]` then checks if the file `hello` exist with write permission.  That is probably not what you were trying to do.  Did yo mean non-zero length string perhaps (-n)?  Also your grep statement needs requires a FILE (perhaps your two files files, or a wildcard like *.txt).